# What is the best way to schedule a task in gemstone?

Tags: scheduling, smalltalk, oodb, gemstone

My website runs on gemstone. To provide users with statistical data I need to run periodical tasks. How is this achieved best in gesmtone? From within gemstone or from the operating system? And would be topaz the right way to go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using something like cron to fire up a topaz process is the right way to go.

Make sure that you capture stdout of the topaz process and include the purpose and date in the name of the log file.

If the frequency of the task is under say every 5 minutes, then firing up a 'permanent' topaz process (like the maintenance vm) sitting on a Delay is a good way to go.

Some of our customers use [CONTROL-M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CONTROL-M) to launch topaz, which includes workflow in it's process scheduling.

Dale

Comment: Hi Dale, didn't expect you here. I didn't expect much gemstone people here. To be honest I was heading for the Tumblweed badge ;) But I like it much more this way

Comment: Norbert,

I think this is a good place to ask questions, since the answers are more accessible. 

Sorry to spoil your quest for a Tumbleweed badge:)

Comment: Silly question - but what is Topaz?
Thanks

Comment: Not silly at all. Topaz is a program that provides command line access to GemStone Smalltalk. It allows one to build Smalltalk scripts that get executed by a gem. You can get more info on GemStone/S at http://gemstonesoup.wordpress.com specifically the 'GemStone 101', 'Docs' and 'Glossary' pages.